# Selected option

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.2

View

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeptId", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "changeDept(this)" })
```

Javascript function

```
function changeDept(ddl) {
    var lastValue = $(ddl).data('lastValue');
    var newValue = $(ddl).val
    var t = $(ddl + ' option:selected').text();

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change from " + $(this).data('lastText') + " to " + ($(this) + 'option:selected').text() + "?")) {
        $(this).data('lastValue', newValue);
    }
    else {
        $(this).val(lastValue);
    }
};

function selectDept(ddl) {
    $(this).data('lastText', $($(this) + ' option:selected').text());
    $(this).data('lastValue', $(this).val());
};
```

ORIGINAL FUNCTION:

```
dept.change(function (e) {
    var lastValue = $(this).data('lastValue');
    var newValue = $(this).val();

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change from " + $(this).data('lastText') + " to " + $('#DeptId option:selected').text() + "?")) {
        $(this).data('lastValue', newValue);
    }
    else {
        $(this).val(lastValue);
    }
});
dept.each(function () {
    //Store old value
    $(this).data('lastText', $('#DeptId option:selected').text());
    $(this).data('lastValue', $(this).val());
});
```

The second way (original function) works, but I want make my function generic, in other words, I want to use it for at least 5 views, so I don't need to make 5 function for each view passing the selector parameter. How can I configure the first form (first function) to make it work?

**ACTUALLY:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DeptId", null, "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "onChange(this)", @onblur = "onBlur(this)" })

function onChange(ddl) {
    var $ddl = $(ddl);
    var lastText = $ddl.data('lastText');
    var lastValue = $ddl.data('lastValue');
    var newText = $ddl.find(':selected').text();
    var newValue = $ddl.val();
    var bool = false;

    if (lastText === undefined) {
        bool = true;
    }

    else if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to change from " + lastText + " to " + newText + "?")) {
        bool = true;
    }

    else {
        bool = false;
        $ddl.val(lastValue);
    }

    if (bool) {
        $ddl.data('lastValue', newValue);
        $ddl.data('lastText', newText);
    }
};
function onBlur(ddl) {
    var selectedOption = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex];
    $(ddl).data('lastText', selectedOption.text).data('lastValue', selectedOption.value);
};
```

My select:

```
<div class="col-md-10">
   <select class="form-control" id="DeptId" name="DeptId" onblur="onBlur(this)" onchange="onChange(this)">
       <option value="">-- Select --</option>
       <option value="1">Clothing</option>
       <option value="2">Eletronics</option>
       <option value="3">Housewares</option>
       <option value="4">Technology</option>
       <option value="5">Accessories</option>
       <option value="6">Perfumary</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Missing `()` at the end in statement `var newValue = $(ddl).val`

Comment: It was just a try.. I know it's wrong. I know ".change(function)" is equivalent to @onchange, and what is equivalent to ".each(function)"? Do you know?

Comment: If I were you, I would stick with the existing functions . As I never recommend ugly inline event handler. You can use simple `for` loop

Comment: Can u show me an example?

Comment: `$($(this) + ' option:selected').text()` doesn't do what you think it does. Change it to `$('option:selected', $(this)).text()`

Comment: Well, yours also do nothing, for me appears "undefined".. I'll edit my document.. if you can, look please..

Comment: I need help with how to retrieve that data I saved in onBlur function, can you help me?

Comment: you use inline handler, so inside it _this_ refers to global object, in this case _window_

Comment: @developer033, so, you want use jQuery, or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use handlers inline html, they call in global context, so `this` inside functions refers to global object, in this case: *window*. So instead `this` keyword you need use passed parameters

```js
function OnChange(ddl) {
  var $ddl = $(ddl);
  var lastValue = $ddl.data('lastValue');
  var newText = $ddl.find(':selected').text();
  var newValue = $ddl.val();

  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change from " + $ddl.data('lastText') + " to " + newText + "?")) {
    $ddl.data('lastValue', newValue);
    $ddl.data('lastText', newText);
  } else {
    $ddl.val(lastValue);
  }

}

function onBlur(ddl) {
  var selectedOption = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex];
  $(ddl).data('lastText', selectedOption.text).data('lastValue', selectedOption.value);

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="OnChange(this)" onblur="onBlur(this)">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE** with disabled

```js
function onChange(ddl) {
  var $ddl = $(ddl);

  var lastText = $ddl.data('lastText'),
    newText = $ddl.find(':selected').text();

  if (!lastText || confirm("Are you sure you want to change from " + lastText + " to " + newText + "?")) {
    $ddl.data('lastValue', $ddl.val());
    $ddl.data('lastText', newText);

  } else {
    $ddl.val($ddl.data('lastValue'));
  }


}

function onBlur(ddl) {
  var selectedOption = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex];
  $(ddl).data('lastText', selectedOption.text).data('lastValue', selectedOption.value);

};

$('select [value=""]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="DeptId" name="DeptId" onblur="onBlur(this)" onchange="onChange(this)">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1">Clothing</option>
  <option value="2">Eletronics</option>
  <option value="3">Housewares</option>
  <option value="4">Technology</option>
  <option value="5">Accessories</option>
  <option value="6">Perfumary</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE2:** seems like you not need *blur* handler because in some browsers like IE, when shows *confirm* select lost focus and raise *blur* handler, and save already selected value, before confirmed.

```js
function onChange(ddl) {
  var $ddl = $(ddl);

  var lastText = $ddl.data('lastText'),
    newText = $ddl.find(':selected').text();

  if (!lastText || confirm("Are you sure you want to change from " + lastText + " to " + newText + "?")) {
    $ddl.data('lastValue', $ddl.val());
    $ddl.data('lastText', newText);

  } else {
    $ddl.val($ddl.data('lastValue'));
  }


}

$('select [value=""]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="DeptId" name="DeptId" onchange="onChange(this)">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  <option value="1">Clothing</option>
  <option value="2">Eletronics</option>
  <option value="3">Housewares</option>
  <option value="4">Technology</option>
  <option value="5">Accessories</option>
  <option value="6">Perfumary</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Great answer, very nice, Thanks! But there is a small error when I select for the first time another element, returns me "Are you sure you want to change from " undefined to NEWVALUE?".. how can I solve this? Thanks more one time.

Comment: @developer033, what behavior you expect for first time? in first time you not save _lastValue_ and _lastText_, so possibly check if `$ddl.data('lastText') === undefined` then not run confirm and just save _lastValue_ and _lastText_

Comment: Nice, it works, I'm newbie in JS, can you help me with a last thing? How can I set "-- Select --" disabled? I saw a lot of examples, but with normal Html (Select) not DropDownList. Can you answer me? -- Btw, I updated my code.

Comment: I was trying something like: `$ddl.find($ddl.val('')).attr('disabled', 'disabled');`

Comment: @developer033, rather `$ddl.find('[value=""]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');`. can you show, how you fill this dropdown? i see you pass _null_

Comment: Did you see? I tried ur solution, but it doesn't works.

Comment: @developer033, try see my updated answer, it seems to work. I possibly not work for you, because you try this before fill dropdown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79615/discussion-between-grundy-and-developer033).